# How do I go about making buttons that reveal lists under them when clicked in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-view

It's hard to put into words what I want but I want a sort of List that reveals  information and different views when expanded and hides them when not expanded. Like this illustration:
[image: visualisation]

Preferably the opening of this tab would also be animated. I really just want all information on one page.

Comment: you need `expendable listview`

Comment: Agreed. See [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/).

Comment: Check this out maybe it will help. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html